# Changing the border color in a Yii2 gridview

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, colors, yii2, border

How do I change the border color inside a Yii2 gridview? I tried searching but I got nothing. I have managed to change the background color but I can't change the border color inside.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The border color is set by bootstrap css. You can add something like this to your css to override it:

```
.table-bordered > thead > tr > th,
.table-bordered > tbody > tr > th,
.table-bordered > tfoot > tr > th,
.table-bordered > thead > tr > td,
.table-bordered > tbody > tr > td,
.table-bordered > tfoot > tr > td {
    border: 1px solid #00a65a;
}
```